# How to fix Passing the JS array to PHP through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have two files, game.js and gallery.php. So I have been trying to send an array from game.js to gallery.php through ajax. I have attached the code I tried , below:

game.js:

```
 imgarray.push({"img_name":img_name,"x":x_value,"y":y_value,"w":w_value,"h":h_value});
   var st = JSON.stringify(imgarray);
        $.ajax({
          url: "gallery.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: { data :st},

          success: function(data){
            console.log(st);
            alert("OK");

          }
      });
```

gallery.php:

```
  <?php
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
    foreach($data as $d){
      echo $d;
   }?>
```

so in the above code , when I run it , in the console log for game.js i am able to print the array. but when I tried to get the array in gallery.php and print it, it throws an error, says st_img is undefined and the for the echo it produces NULL.

Can someone help me fix this.

Comment: You're logging `st` in the success callback in game.js, which is the variable from *before* the ajax call—so that's not going to tell you whether the server did what you wanted. Log `data` instead—that's the server response.

Comment: Are you sure that your PHP script throws an exception? I'm not a PHP expert, but accessing an absent property on the `$_POST` hash shouldn't throw an exception... and if it did, it wouldn't even get to the next line, which you claim prints `NULL`.

Comment: @weltschmerz i tried with log data, now it throws an error => "Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"